# Can I select a list of tables that have records in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a backup of a database restored to my server which has over 100 tables, but I know that only a few of them have records. Is it possible to write a query that would select a list of tables that contain records? This is SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab_info
( 
    [name] NVARCHAR(128),
    [rows] CHAR(11),
    reserved VARCHAR(18), 
    data VARCHAR(18), 
    index_size VARCHAR(18),
    unused VARCHAR(18)
) 

INSERT #tab_info EXEC sp_msForEachTable 'EXEC sp_spaceused ''?''' 

SELECT *
FROM   #tab_info
WHERE [rows] > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a go:

```
SELECT so.name,
       ps.row_count
FROM   sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
       INNER JOIN sys.objects so
         ON ps.object_id = so.object_id
WHERE  so.type = 'u'
       AND row_count > 0
ORDER  BY so.name
```

Might be worth noting that 100% accuracy isn't guaranteed on the row counts (this info is only meant as a guideline for the Query optimiser, I believe) if you needed it to be accurate there's nothing like running an actual table scan with `COUNT`.

However since you just want to check if there are any rows, this should be sufficient.